# How to fix a CORS error for a custom font?

Tags: css, font-face, custom-font

A custom font I've uploaded isn't showing on Firefox or Chrome, although it's working on Safari and mobile devices. I'm getting a CORS error "CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'".

Could it be the stylesheet link?

(link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://go.pardot.com/l/752313/2019-06-15/pfv/752313/4021/1711_JKVABE.css")

Here is the link to the page: http://go.pardot.com/l/752313/2019-06-07/g4s

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Canela Web';
        src: url('http://go.pardot.com/l/752313/2019-06-15/pfs/752313/4019/Canela_Regular_Web.eot');
        src: url('http://go.pardot.com/l/752313/2019-06-15/pfs/752313/4019/Canela_Regular_Web.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('http://go.pardot.com/l/752313/2019-06-15/pfn/752313/4015/Canela_Regular_Web.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('http://go.pardot.com/l/752313/2019-06-15/pfq/752313/4017/Canela_Regular_Web.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        }

    .Canela-Regular-Web {
        font-family: 'Canela Web';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        }
```

Comment: You should use `local()` first and then fallback to `url()`. The actual error is because of your loading from `storage.` subdomain, if you control that system then add correct cors headers to allow origin from the `go.` subdomain

Comment: Thank you, I added the local(Canela Web) first. I'm not sure why it's trying to lead from storage. instead of go.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To fix this specific error, CSP should include this:

```
font-src 'self' data:;
```

So, in head tag this meta should be set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:;">
```